# Visually combine neighbouring CSS blocks without javascript

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a site which has editable content via a WYSIWYG inline editor, and users who are very unlikely to understand the need to put containing DIV around similar blocks of code for formatting, resulting in html similar to:

```
<div class="borderBlock">Content...</div>
<div class="borderBlock">Content...</div>
<div>Other content</div>
<div class="borderBlock">Content...</div>
```

with current CSS along the lines of:

```
.borderBlock {
margin: 8px 0;
border: 1px solid;
border-radius: 4px;
}
```

This gives each div it's own separate border - not quite what is wanted, ideally the first two div's would share a border and background colour!

I know that I can use css such as:

```
:not(.borderBlock) + .borderBlock { }
```

to select the first block of class borderBlock - applying formatting for the start of a block, and similarly:

```
.borderBlock + :not(.borderBlock)
```

would select the first none borderBlock element... but I can't find a way to select the last borderBlock element in a block that isn't specifically surrounded by another div - in the above html using :last-child or :last-child-of-type would both select only the fourth div, and not style the second div as the end of a borderBlock. Similarly :first-child(-of-kind) would not style the second bordered block.

Is there a CSS solution to this that doesn't use JavaScript, and doesn't involve putting a containing div around each required bordered block?  Something equivalent to a CSS look-ahead regular expression rather than the standard CSS look-behind style.

Comment: You can give the impression that they share a border by specifying `border-right: none` on the left div, and `border-left:none` on the right div, or however you want it set up

Comment: @Andy: this would need to know which the first and last divs were, which I don't know since they are being input by non-technical users - the CSS styling isn't the issue, the question is can the divs to style be identified with CSS alone, and no extra HTML or JavaScript

Comment: Are you aware of the :first-child and :last-child pseudo classes? They will tell you the first and last divs and style them appropriately

Comment: @Andy: yes, I am, however as stated in the original question first child would pick out the first div, last child the last div - however the desired effect is that the second div being the last successive div with the same class is identified as a last child, the final div should identify as both a first and last child of it's class (or only child possibly) - the overall containing div may have several sets of the borderBlock class grouped together, and it is the groupings that I wish to locate - the first block in each group may not be a first child, the last block not a last child.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, you cannot do this with CSS selectors, without using JavaScript or modifying your HTML, since there's no preceding sibling selector.

Comment: That was the answer I was coming to unfortunately - I was rather hoping that someone may have a way around it, but it appears not!

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this?:

http://jsfiddle.net/Hegxc/4/

using :first-of-type and :last-of-type

Is that what you're trying to achieve or have I misunderstood what you're looking for??

Comment: not quite - this is more a demonstration of why :first... and :last... don't hit the mark. [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Hegxc/7/) is more what I need, but without the outer div to combine the first two divs, as that requires html knowledge the users don't have!

Comment: `:first-of-type` and `:last-of-type` refer to tag name, not class name.